# Query was empty, and other errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on this for over a month now and cannot see any error in this code. It worked fine until about two months ago. I started getting this error: **Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in functions.php on line 41** (line 41 is $num=mysql_num_rows($result);). I made sure it was connecting with the database and checked my brackets all over the file. When I check for errors using mysql_error I get hung up on **Query was empty** on line 40 as seen below. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out by reading posts here on stackoverflow, but need a little more help. Thanks.

```
function query_sql($sql)
{
$username="somename";
$password="mypassword";
$database="database2";
$link=mysql_connect("sqlserver.myserver.net",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database,$link);
$result = mysql_query ($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
return $result;
}
```

Here is the code from the main page that included the $sql variable.

```
<?php
include 'modules/functions.php';
update_log($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "");
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    $User = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $sql = "select Username from users where Username = '".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
    $get_results = query_sql($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_results);
}
else
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}

$sql = 'select Name, Category, Category2, Private, Staff from users where Username = "'.$User.'"';
$get_user_access = query_sql($sql);
$sql = '';
```

Comment: "Query was empty" means your `$sql` variable is an empty string. What did you pass to your function? Debug that.

Comment: I have edited the main post to include more of the code, thanks.

Comment: The code as shown won't even run: `$get_user_access $get_user_access = query_sql($sql);`. Show us the code you're actually running.

Comment: `$get_results = query_sql($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");` You're not returning false on error so this is just wrong.

Comment: The double $get_user_access was a typo on my part, not in the code its self.

Comment: So I need to remove the error reporting?  @PhilipWhitehouse

Comment: If you take out the @ on `@mysql_select_db($database,$link);` you might find out why you failed to select the database.

Comment: @grahamj42 I tried that, but did not find anything else out, even after adding mysql_error.

Answer (score 1):

Start by commenting out or deleting the `mysql_close();` in the `query_sql()` function definition.

Here is the reasoning behind this

After you call `mysql_close()` and then call the `mysql_fetch_assoc($get_results);` PHP will attempt to reconnect to the database using the default settings - but with no active SQL query to get the number of rows/fetch the data it errors out.

Here's my suggestion - don't repeatedly open and close the database connection, open it at the top - run all your queries and either close it at the bottom or let it close with the PHP garbage collector at the end of the script.

Comment: I tried this, but still get the same "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result" error.

Comment: did you get any specific mysql errors? or just the PHP error?